# Wrap text dynamically depending on screen size?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a modal form that I want the text to wrap depending on the size of the modal form. What is the proper css for that?

Currently I am using the angular with new lines and I am hardcoding the line breaks. The problem is the line break stays if the screen is larger and it makes the text look awkward and not centered.

```
.angular-with-newlines {
white-space: pre-wrap !important; 
   }

.text-center{
text-align: center !important;
```

}

My html `

```
<div class="row text-center margin30">
      <h5 class=" angular-with-newlines">{{message}}</h5>    
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure what suppose to be the final result.

Comment: I have a modal and I have a message that looks like this "Error was found. \nPlease fix errors before proceeding" . So i use the whitespace -pre so the line break is captured correctly. If the user clicks a button it shows the error in detail in a grid. The grid is large in width so themodal is also expanded in width. Since the grid expands the size of the modal width then there is plenty of space for the message to fit on a single line. I want the message to be dynamically wrapped based on the size of the modal. If there is  space then use it all. If there isn't then wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the media query like below-

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
.text-center{
text-align: center !important;
}
}
```

Comment: This isn't working I have appended my question in the comment above